# Reverse search: backward rewarding?

Tags: phrase-request

I once read an article and encountered a word which I only remember its meaning is backward rewarding. One example is that one works hard and s/he will not be rewarded immediately but once s/he is promoted or his/her salary is raised the previous hard-work would be rewarded backward.

I have searched some reverse search engines like https://reversedictionary.org/, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Isn't a [reward](https://www.lexico.com/definition/reward) always retrospective, and not necessarily immediate?

Comment: The phrase this sounds like to me is [“All her hard work will pay off.”](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/kevin_hart_681201), meaning that even though you worked for a long time with no reward, that work is an investment that will make a difference between success and failure at some future opportunity. Is that the sort of thing you mean by “backward rewarding”?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, the phrase I thought should be `retrospective assessment`.

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for your comment.

Comment: There is the concept of _deferred gratification_ which could be considered here.

Comment: @mdewey Great! I have noted down that also.